# Java - Superclass/Subclass

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

Slight problem here:

```
public class Item extends ItemManufacturer
{
// Attributes
private String itemcode;
private String itemname;
private String description;
private String style;
private String finish;
private float  unitprice;
private float  stock;

public void item(String suppliercodeIn, String suppliernameIn, String addressIn, String itemcodeIn, String itemnameIn, String descriptionIn, 
            String styleIn, String finishIn, float unitpriceIn, float stockIn)
  {
       super ( suppliercodeIn, suppliernameIn, addressIn );

       itemcode = itemcodeIn;
       itemname = itemnameIn;
       description = descriptionIn;
       style = styleIn;
       finish = finishIn;
       unitprice = unitpriceIn;
       stock = stockIn;
  }
```

I am getting the following error message:

> Call to super must be first statement in constructor.

Would anyone care to help me out with this?

Is an additional error I am getting, after toying around with the classes.

```
// Create a Item oject
Item item = new Item();
```

I am using a database called items and a table name of item.

Comment: Also, I'm skeptical of the class hierarchy if the names are meaningful.

Answer (score 4):

This is the problem:

```
public void item(...)
```

That's not a constructor for an `Item` class - it's a void method called `item`. It should be:

```
public Item(...)
```

Note that Java is case-sensitive, and a constructor doesn't have a declared return type; it's *just* accessibility followed by the name of the class, followed by the parameter list.

Comment: @silverj2k7: Are you sure you've got the name of the constructor matching the name of the class? Did you fix the case of `item`?

Comment: public class Item extends ItemManufacturer
 {
    // Attributes
    private String itemcode;
    private String itemname;
    private String description;
    private String style;
    private String finish;
    private float  unitprice;
    private float  stock;
   
    /* 
     * Constructor method for item
    */
    public Item(String suppliercodeIn, String suppliernameIn, String addressIn, String itemcodeIn, String itemnameIn, String descriptionIn

Comment: sorry about that, and yes. I did have it fixed at one point but then I needed to spilt the item class into two classes other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect a typo. Your constructor should be called `Item` not `item`. (And constructors don't return anything, not even `void`.)

As for the `new` expression: you need to pass in all those parameters when you create a new instance of `Item`.

```
Item item = new Item("234SD23", "SuperSupplier", "21 SO Drive", ...);
```

Comment: That means you haven't defined such a constructor for your ItemManufacturer class (or possibly typoes there too).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I made that mistake in both the item and itemanufacturer class.

Comment: The second most hounding error this this:
   
                       // Create a Item oject
                       Item item = new Item();

Cannot find symbol - constructor Item()

Comment: Edited. You seem to need to read a good Java book and/or tutorial, this is very, very basic.

Comment: Well you'll have to redesign, or create the Item object later when you have all the required strings.

Answer (score 0):

Read this,

1. If there is no typo, and item is an method, then super(), wont work. You need to do super.item();
2. If there is a typo, and its Item not item, then there will be NO return type,

   eg:

   ```
   public Item (String suppliercodeIn, String suppliernameIn, String addressIn,
       String itemcodeIn, String itemnameIn, String descriptionIn, 
       String styleIn, String finishIn, float unitpriceIn, float stockIn){

   }
   ```

Comment: So there isn't a typo, so super.item(); would be for? Sorry too many ITEMS I am getting easily confused now =/

Comment: @silverj2k7: the space doesn't matter. Kumar's first point is that you could have wanted to call a method called `item` in the superclass. But that's not what you want.

Comment: Itementry screen is where I am trying to create the new object which is referencing the sub-class.